# Engine Scanner: is this a Rich Condition?

Tags: dtc

2013 Accent 1.6 GDI 255K miles. 20K ago I replaced converter. Within that time I've replaced plugs, coils, cam and crank sensors, O2 and AF (Lamba) sensors. I'm getting an intermittent 420 code and wonder if it could be a rich condition causing it. I base this on the following numbers from my scanner:

> STFT = -0.8 LTFT = 7.8
>
> Downstream O2 = 0.670 Upstream Wideband Lambda = 0.961 Upstream mA = -0.15.

I tested that the O2 and Lambda sensors are working by snapping the throttle and confirming a brief lean condition and by using propane in the intake I induced a rich condition. I've confirmed that the PCV and fuel tank vapor line aren't the cause of the rich condition. I can see the MAP sensor reading as expected while driving.

Could it be a fuel injector issue? Barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: It could be a vacuum leak somewhere on the Intake manifold or between the manifold and the MAF.

Comment: code 0420 is a catalyst efficiency code, usually means a cat (between the 2 OS sensors) is failing.